# How to get the ROWID from a Progress database

Tags: database, progress-4gl, progress-db

I have a Progress database that I'm performing an ETL from.  One of the tables that I'm reading from does not have a unique key on it, so I need to access the ROWID to be able to uniquely identify the row.  What is the syntax for accessing the ROWID in Progress?

I understand there are problems with using ROWID for row identification, but it's all I have right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick caveat for my answer - it's nearly 10 years since I worked with [Progress](http://www.progress.com/) so my knowledge is probably more than a little out of date.

Checking the [Progress Language Reference](http://www.psdn.com/library/servlet/KbServlet/download/1078-102-885/langref.pdf) [PDF] seems to show the two functions I remember are still there: `ROWID` and `RECID`.  The `ROWID` function is newer and is preferred.

In Progress 4GL you'd use it something like this:

```
FIND customer WHERE cust-num = 123.
crowid = ROWID(customer).
```

or:

```
FIND customer WHERE ROWID(customer) = crowid EXCLUSIVE-LOCK.
```

Checking the [Progress SQL Reference](http://www.psdn.com/library/servlet/KbServlet/download/1223-102-1092/s92.pdf) [PDF] shows `ROWID` is also available in SQL as a Progress extension.  You'd use it like so:

```
SELECT ROWID, FirstName, LastName FROM customer WHERE cust-num = 123
```

**Edit:** Edited following Stefan's feedback.

Comment: You should put a NO-ERROR on the first two examples, and on the first add an IF AVAIL customer THEN before assigning the ROWID. As an alternative, you could put the assign statement inside of a FOR FIRST CUSTOMER NO-LOCK WHERE... Just ways to avoid error messages if there is no matching customer.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your situation and the behavior of the application this may or may not matter but you should be aware that ROWIDs & RECIDs are reused and that they may change.

1) If a record is deleted it's ROWID will eventually be reused.

2) If the table is reorganized via a dump & load or a tablemove to a new storage area then the ROWIDs will change.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a little to Dave Webb's answers.  I had tried ROWID in the select statement but was given a syntax error.  ROWID only works if you specify the rest of the columns to select, you cannot use *.

This does NOT work:

```
SELECT ROWID, * FROM customer WHERE cust-num = 123
```

This does work:

```
SELECT ROWID, FirstName, LastName FROM customer WHERE cust-num = 123
```

Comment: THat's good to know.  When I was working with Progress it was all about the 4GL and SQL support was pretty new so I never queried a Progess DB with SQL.  That said from what I remember it's a great database with a nice architecture and it's a shame it's so rarely used.

Comment: once you specify a column, you have to prefix * with the table name. So, in the example, `SELECT RowID, "cust-num".* FROM ...` **would** work

Answer (score -2):

A quick google search turns up this: 
http://bytes.com/forum/thread174440.html

Read the message towards the bottom by greg@turnstep.com (you either want oid or ctid depending on what guarantees you want re persistence and uniqueness)

Comment: I have a Progress database, not a PostgreSQL database.